# How to make regex using two condition

Tags: regex

I want to make url validate using Regex.
So I made as below.
First, it must be started with 'https://'
Second, it must have '.' inside of the URL.
I made the first condition. But I don't know how to attach the second condition together.

```
/(^https:\/\/)/g
```

Thank you for reading. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: maybe this help you `/(^https:\/\/.*\..*)/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to check that character `.` come after https://, maybe this helps you:

```
/(^https:\/\/.*\..*)/g
```

- Note that this pattern is not a reliable pattern to validate link.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check for the dot you can use:

```
/(^https:\/\/)[^\.]*\..*$/g
```

I also found somthing on Regextester:

```
/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/g
```

You can adjust this to your needs by removing some modifiers:

```
/^https:\/\/[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/g
```

Try it for yourself. [Regextester](https://www.regextester.com/94502)